# In what contexts would I say "I'm suggesting" as opposed to "I suggest"?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Can you please tell me in what contexts I would say *I'm suggesting* as opposed to *I suggest*? For example, is there any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> **I suggest** we stop by this restaurant because they serve delicious food.
>
> **I'm suggesting** we stop by this restaurant because they serve delicious food.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would say "I suggest" in the moment that you make the suggestion. So:

> I suggest [we go to] this restaurant.

is what you'd say if you want to make the suggestion.

On the other hand, I'm suggesting would typically be used as an explanation of something you've already suggested.

> Well, I've been telling you for the past week that the food there is
> great; obviously I'm suggesting that we go there for our anniversary.

I think this is consistent with the general use of the continuous to denote an ongoing activity. That being said, you could also use "I'm suggesting" in place of "I suggest," - i.e. at the moment of making the suggestion - but, in my opinion, "I'm suggesting" when used this way gives the impression that a period of thought, deliberation or even debate has preceded the suggestion.

> Ok, we've been sitting around talking indecisively about restaurants
> for an hour. I'm suggesting we get up and go to the Grasshopper Grille
> right now.

Answer (score 0):

I **suggest** we stop by this restaurant because they serve delicious food.
That is the **usual** one for making a straight suggestion.

I'm suggest**ing** we stop by this restaurant because they serve delicious food.
This is used when people are **arguing** about something or otherwise not in agreement or debating something.

Son: Why can't we do that? I want to do it that way.
Father: Well, I'm suggesting you shouldn't because of [blah blah blah].

**Similar to**: Yep, I **speak** English. I really do. In fact, I'm **speaking** English to you right now.